# How to plot two y-axes in Excel 2003 with Python

Tags: python, excel-2003

I'm trying to plot two data series with different y-axes in the same plot in Excel 2003 using Python and win32com.client. I started with VBA to try to get the code I needed. Here's what it looks like so far:

```
chart = xlApp.Charts.Add()

# This part successfully creates the first series I want

series = chart.SeriesCollection(1)
series.XValues = xlSheet.Range("L13:L200")
series.Values = xlSheet.Range("M13:M200")

# This is what I added to try to plot the second series

series.AxisGroup = xlPrimary
series2 = chart.SeriesCollection(2)
series2.XValues = xlSheet.Range("L13:L200")
series2.Values = xlSheet.Range("N13:N200")
series2.AxisGroup = xlSecondary

# The rest is for formatting it the way I want, but it doesn't work now that I'm
# to plot the second series. (It stops working when I add the last five lines of code).

chart.Legend.Delete() # Delete legend; MUST BE DONE BEFORE CHART IS MOVED
series.Name = file
chart.Location(2, xlSheet.Name) # Copy chart to active worksheet
chart = xlSheet.Shapes(1)
chart.Top = 51
chart.Left = 240
chart.Width = 500
chart.Height = 350
```

This plots the first series, but as noted in the comments, no longer adds the title, moves the chart, deletes the legend or resizes the chart. It does nothing with the second series. It is also not generating an error.

Comment: Which library are you using to manipulate the spreadsheet / Excel?

Comment: @necaris - win32com.client. Thanks, I added that to my question.

Comment: Note that in the line

`chart = xlSheet.Shapes(1)`
you're reassigning the chart name to another object (`xlSheet.Shapes(1)`), and so when you perform subsequent actions on `chart` they'll no longer affect the original `chart` -- is that what you want? To be working on a fresh chart?

Comment: If I understand what's going on there, I am selecting the shape at index 1 on the current sheet and then changing the size. It's the last thing I do to it, so I don't think it matters. If I remember correctly I need to select it that way after I move it. I suppose I could resize it first.

Comment: Yep, AFAICT that's the correct understanding -- but is the chart the shape at index 1? If it's just been copied in to the active sheet, perhaps it's at index > 1? The reason I homed in on that was because you state in the question that it stops working after that line of code...